# How to login AzureRm using ConnectionType as Azure in AzureAutomation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

My Azure Automation is created using `Create Azure Run As Account`

I can able to login to Azure using the below commands

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
```

I'm now investigating about the connectiontype as `Azure`

I've created a new connection as **Azure Type** by uploading my own certificate in Certificate

**My Own certificate in Automation**

[image]

**My Azure Connection**

[image]

Now I'm thinking how can use this `abc` connection to login into my Azure Rm Account

```
$connectionName = "abc"
$conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
echo $conn
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionId $conn.SubscriptionID
```

I know the above it's not the correct approach, but hoping someone will help me to get the correct one.

The above query is giving the error like below

```
Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
AutomationCertificateName      MyCertificate                                                                            
SubscriptionID                 xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx


Logging in to Azure...
Connect-AzureRmAccount : Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.
At line:5 char:5
+     Connect-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionId $conn.SubscriptionID
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Also, I couldn't get any reference document for the exact usage of `connectionType` as **Azure**. I couldn't get any example [except this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureRM.Automation/New-AzureRmAutomationConnection?view=azurermps-6.7.0#description) related to connectiontype as **Azure**

It would be a great help if someone guide to get some reference document on the connectionType as **Azure**

Comment: Did you pass the TenantId, Certificate ThumbPrint and ApplicationId with it ?

Comment: @HariHaran yes tried not working with `Azure` connectionType, but as i mentioned above it's working for `AzureServicePrinicple` connectiontype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already opened a Github [issue already](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7048) which got resolved today. For someone who is still trying to get the answer, pls look at the [detailed documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-connections#connection-types).

> **Azure** - This connection can be used to manage classic resources.
>   **AzureClassicCertificate** - This connection is used by the
>   AzureClassicRunAs account. 
> **AzureServicePrincipal** - This connection is
>   used by the AzureRunAs account.

Answer (score 0):

An Azure Run As Account is not just a Connection and Certificate asset.

There's also an Azure AD application, Azure AD service principal and contributor permissions assigned for that service principal during the creation of an Azure Run As Account.

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account for more information. The docs also contain a PowerShell script for creating your own Azure Run As Account, which includes support for the following configurations:

- Create a Run As account by using a self-signed certificate.
- Create a Run As account and a Classic Run As account by using a
  self-signed certificate.
- Create a Run As account and a Classic Run As account by using a
  certificate issued by your enterprise certification authority (CA).
- Create a Run As account and a Classic Run As account by using a
  self-signed certificate in the Azure Government cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can able to understand about the `RunAsAccount` connectiontype. But my question how can we login into Azure RM using `Azure` connectiontype ?

Comment: If you look at the script in the URL provided, you'll see it actually creates a Certificate and Connection for you. But this allows you to customize it (for instance using your own certificate), it will also add the other requirements for this to work.